# How to collapse/join selected factor levels across two columns in R

Tags: r

Let's say I have the following data frame:

```
x <-c(rep (c ("s1", "s2", "s3"),each=5 ))
y <- c(rep(c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), 3) )               
z<-c(1:15)    

x_name <- "dimensions"
y_name <- "aspects"
z_name<-"value"
df <- data.frame(x,y,z)
names(df) <- c(x_name,y_name, z_name)
```

How can I collapse/join factor levels 'a', 'c', 'd' in one new factor 'x' across 'dimensions' and 'value', so that the value is added up for the new x factor level. The output should look like this:

[image]

I thought to use gsub to replace the names of a,c, d, with x and then sum their values using aggregate. But is there a simpler way to do this? Besides I am not sure my solution would be still good if I have other columns containing a, c, d.
I reviewed several related answers on the forum but neither addressed this situation. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First rename a, c, and d to x and then sum by dimensions and aspects

Reading the data:

```
df <- data.frame(dimensions = x, aspects = y, value = z, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Base R solution:

```
# if you read the data my way the following line is unnecessary
# df$aspects <- as.character(df$aspects) 
df[df$aspects %in% c("a","c","d"),]$aspects <- "x"
aggregate(value ~., df, sum)
```

Result:

```
  dimensions aspects value
1         s1       b     2
2         s2       b     7
3         s3       b    12
4         s1       e     5
5         s2       e    10
6         s3       e    15
7         s1       x     8
8         s2       x    23
9         s3       x    38
```

`data.table` solution

```
require(data.table)
DT <- setDT(df)
DT[aspects %in% c("a","c","d"), aspects := "x"]
DT[,sum(value), by=.(dimensions, aspects)]
```

Results in

```
   dimensions aspects V1
1:         s1       x  8
2:         s1       b  2
3:         s1       e  5
4:         s2       x 23
5:         s2       b  7
6:         s2       e 10
7:         s3       x 38
8:         s3       b 12
9:         s3       e 15
```

Comment: It works well and seems simpler than my initial solution. Thanks.

Comment: Pierre Lafortune, what do you mean by your comment?

Comment: The question asks for recoding by 'a', 'c', 'd' **not** 'a', 'b', 'c' - a simple edit will fix your solution.

Comment: I did notice that but it works either way, so thanks all

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using `plyr::revalue` (see also `plyr::mapvalues`) and `dplyr`:

```
# install.packages("plyr")
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(aspects = plyr::revalue(aspects, c("a" = "x", "c" = "x", "d" = "x"))) %>%
  group_by(dimensions, aspects) %>%
  summarise(sum_value = sum(value))

#   dimensions aspects sum_value
#       (fctr)  (fctr)     (int)
# 1         s1       x         8
# 2         s1       b         2
# 3         s1       e         5
# 4         s2       x        23
# 5         s2       b         7
# 6         s2       e        10
# 7         s3       x        38
# 8         s3       b        12
# 9         s3       e        15
```

Comment: JasonAizkalns I am using the code, but it appears that it adds 'b' too leaving just x (that includes the value of b too) and e.

Comment: Thanks. It still gives me an other output. I will upvote it and will try to figure out what goes wrong. I see that you install 'plyr' but the request is for 'dplyr'. Could it be this? (have not used dplyr or plyr so far so do not have any idea)